# What recommended upload/download speeds should I have for a Quake 1 server?

Tags: hosting, quake

I know that this sounds extremely outdated to talk about, but what are some recommended Internet speeds for a Quake 1 server? I've been catering to the lone players looking around on the DarkPlaces master server, and for some reason, the lag in my server is ridiculous! It's a game from 1996, and I still can't understand why this is happening.

I think the main problem I have is that I'm using a wireless connection to do this, but again, it's Quake! I should be able to handle this! I also have cruddy Internet speeds, around 10mbps for download, and a measly 1mbps for upload. When I get the chance, I'm getting a Raspberry Pi 2, and connecting it over ethernet to run servers like this. I also would like to note that I used to run servers for Garry's Mod and the like, and they are alright, but I had a better Wi-Fi dongle then, and Garry's Mod has client-side prediction.
As a summation:

I am using the DarkPlaces engine, I am using a 150mbps Wi-Fi dongle, and I have 10mbps download 1mbps upload.

What recommended upload/download speeds should I have for a Quake 1 server?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the specific numbers for Quake 1 nor the DarkPlaces variant of the engine but for a Quake 2 dedicated server it is recommended to have 2.5-2.8 kbps of bandwidth per player. I would expect that Quake 1 would be around the same or less and will update if I find anything specific to Quake 1.

The Dark Places engine has support for [multiple protocols](https://github.com/Blub/darkplaces/blob/master/protocol.c), the default should be DP7 which in comparison to the original Quake network protocol is quite bandwidth efficient but comes with a downside of only other players running Dark Places can connect. You could try enabling this if it isn't already, certainly if you're using the default Quake protocols as these are less bandwidth efficient. The protocol can be changed with the command `sv_protocolname`.

That said, with the bandwidth you have available I doubt you'd experience any issue in hosting a large Quake server so I would look for other potential causes (not bandwidth related) to the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I am using Quake 1, with the DarkPlaces engine. Also, don't post in answers to ask questions. I don't want to vote you down, or anyone else.

Comment: So, obviously, it's probably my Wi-Fi dongle. It really sucks, and the reason I'm using it is because I recently moved to using Linux, and my old 300mbps dongle did not have usable drivers available for Linux. I'm ordering a new one soon, it's one of the more popular dongles for Linux.

Comment: Well you could check ping/jitter/etc with speedtest.net and pingtest.net to see if that's the problem

Comment: Protocol name is already DP7.

Comment: speedtest.net and pingtest.net require flash, and since Flash is a b**ch, they stopped supporting Linux systems.

Comment: @SpecialBomb SpeedTest.net has a mobile app that might help

Comment: @Burgi My phone is fine, and so is my network speed. My dad's computer has a farther internet connection, and is using a better Wi-Fi dongle. I downloaded an album on both our computers, and it took over an hour for my computer to download, while for my dad, his took about 10 minutes. It's my Wi-Fi dongle, I'm sure of it.

Comment: use http://speedof.me/ or http://testmy.net/upload . These both were found here http://lmgtfy.com/?q=flashless+speed+test

Answer (score -1):

It's my Wi-Fi dongle. The thing is too slow for anything. I have proved this by comparing download speeds of two computers on my network. One that had my dongle, and another that had a better dongle (I used to use this one, but since I use Linux now, it doesn't work because the linux drivers for it are REALLY bad). My computer downloaded an album I like listen to that is about 454 MB, and it took about an hour. The other computer downloaded it within 10 minutes. Obviously, I haven't checked for upload speed, but I'm pretty sure my awnser is that the other dongle is better, as I have ran servers fine with it before. I'm ordering a new dongle that is better than the best one that I have described, and is compatible with Linux.

Comment: @Serverfrog Sorry about that rambling at the end, I'm extremely passonate about Quake. But, I'm not supposed to do this here; This is StackExcange.